# mysql trigger after update

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update, database-trigger

i want to create a mysql trigger to manipulate a column

this is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER gestion_absences after update
ON Etudiant FOR EACH ROW
begin 
if( NEW.Present = 'Non') 
then
update Etudiant set Nbr_Absences = (OLD.Nbr_Absences) + 1 where (NEW.Present) = 'Non';
end if;
End;
```

the error is:

> # 1064 - Syntax error near '' at line 6

I don't know where is the problem

I want when a student is absent  , le number is incremented by 1;
if he's present , do nothing.

Comment: This specific trigger would be better if you dont use an `after update` because you could enter a loop. BTW I would suggest changing the error message into english.

Comment: # 1064 - Syntax error near '' at line 6

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the same table in your trigger AFTER updating it.  However, you may create the trigger BEFORE update and set the correct values for Nbr_Absences if present is Non.

```
CREATE TRIGGER gestion_absences BEFORE UPDATE ON Etudiant 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.Present = 'Non' THEN
SET new.Nbr_Absences = old.Nbr_Absences + 1;
END IF;
END
;
```

Comment: okey , I get it , but when i tried your code  , the error still present (# 1064 - Syntax error near '' at line 5).